# Anthology of SF short stories, one involving scientists discovering planet that produced every life form in existence

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, space-exploration

I think this anthology consisted of five short stories.

One was where explorers landed on a alien planet and were killed one by one by alien life forms. One of the forms mimicked the night sky and slowly descended on one of the explorers as they slept. Sentient plants may have killed another one of the explorers.

Another story involved researchers finding what they called a god planet, in which the planet produced life then sent it out to seed the universe of other universes. Only, when they discover and try to recreate how life is created on the planet, they discovered they destroyed the ability for the planet to create life and therefore completely destroying the ability for any new life to be created for the remander of time. Maybe one of the scientists commits suicide as a result because she thinks they destroyed god?

My memory of the other stories is even more sparse. One may have involved an individual becoming involved with a cult in which developed a hallucinogen from the planet they colonized that allowed them to read minds.

Hope this is enough information. I read it as a kid pretty far back. Book could have been published anywhere from 70s to 90s, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 2):

I am lucky to be able to answer this because I, too, read this as a kid long ago. But wouldn't have remembered if I hadn't come across a connection as an adult.  A couple years ago, I read the book Midworld, by Alan Dean Foster, which is the full length novel of the world that your aforementioned "night sky" camouflaged predator originally comes from (a really good book, btw).

But, that isn't the book you are looking for. You will recognize the theme of the stories you remember, they all involve bad news planets.

You most likely were a member of the Science Fiction Book Club, like I was, because this anthology was written for club members.  It is called "Forbidden Planets," edited by Marvin Kaye.

https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1809574.Forbidden_Planets